# su: Permission denied as root

Tags: active-directory, su

I added my Ubuntu Machine to AD and I can do an ID these user accounts
but when I'm logged in as root I can't su to these accounts
e.g.

```
su: Permission denied
```

any reason why?
is there something I miss configuring?

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu doesn’t have a root account by default so what have you done to be logged in as root?

Comment: I did sudo su -

Comment: any user sudo privileges can't su -

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to sudo su. sudo seeks elevated permissions while su means switch user. Can you su to the users you have passwords for

Comment: so unlike centos I can't su as another user in Ubuntu even as root?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with centos but in general you use su to execute commands as the user you specify. In Ubuntu you will get prompted for that users password. This link might help https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usu.htm

Comment: sudo doesn’t make you the root user it temporarily gives raised privileges to your user

Comment: You should use sudo -i to go to root shell.